# Activator.CreateInstance throws 'System.MissingMethodException' when using CoreCLR

Tags: c#, reflection, asp.net-core, dnx, coreclr

I'm trying to create an instance of a class in my CoreCLR app, but when I call Activator.CreateInstance, I get a System.MissingMethodException saying that it can't find a constructor on the class it's trying to create. The class indeed has a constructor. What am I doing wrong?

The project is only targeting dnxcore50.

This is the code:

```
using System;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Program
    {
        public void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (MyClass), true);
        }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass() { }
    }
}
```

And this is the exception:

```
System.MissingMethodException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233069
  Message=Constructor on type 'MyNamespace.MyClass' not found.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
       at MyNamespace.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\projects\coreclrplayground\InvokeMember\src\InvokeMember\Program.cs:line 9
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On CoreCLR, `Activator` doesn't have an overload accepting a boolean parameter indicating whether non-public constructors can be used to instantiate the type.

Your snippet builds correctly because the compiler chooses the `CreateInstance(Type type, params object[] args)` overload, which treats your boolean like a constructor parameter: since your constructor is parameterless, an exception is thrown.